# my post was deleted

Tags: support

I have a question about my Super User post: [File Server - Is it possible to allow users to view all files but don't allow them to access them](https://superuser.com/questions/1544582/file-server-is-it-possible-to-allow-users-to-view-all-files-but-dont-allow-th/1544587#1544587)

the question was "user's can't see all folders, how do i get users to see all folders in a share."
my answer was "you have access-based enumeration enabled."
my post was deleted. 
somebody else answered "you have access-based enumeration enabled," and that post wasn't deleted. i'm confused.

Comment: The tone of your answer implies it is a comment asking for clarification, rather than a statement of fact. You present a *possibility* of something it *might* be then ask how something is happening. Answers should not be used to seek clarification. That makes it a comment. The other answer is a statement of fact "because *this* and you fix it *like this*". While your answer and the other one is similar in getting to the core of what might cause the problem, they are worlds apart in terms of focusing on *authoritatively solving the problem*.

Answer (score 5):

#### I'm confused.

Your answer was

> it sounds like "access based enumeration" is enabled. is the users folder shared as \server\users, or are users logging directly into your server and browsing to c:\users locally?

"It sounds like is not an answer".

You then went on to ask for more information.

That make your answer a comment not an answer.

> somebody else answered "you have access-based enumeration enabled"

That answer did not ask any further questions and went on to explain how to resolve the issue (which your did not).

Comment: That other answer went on to explain for a whole one sentence!

Comment: Your entire answer was a question.  As my answer points out, the other answer is an extremely low quality answer that perhaps should be downvoted, but it still answers the author’s question.

Answer (score 3):

> the question was "user's can't see all folders, how do i get users to see all folders in a share." my answer was "you have access-based enumeration enabled." my post was deleted.

You submitted a question within an answer, that read and was interpreted by multiple individuals reviewing your answers as a question you wanted an answer to.  At no point did you provide clear instructions on how the author of the question could solve their problem.

I specifically remember your answer in the low quality review queue.

> somebody else answered "you have access-based enumeration enabled," and that post wasn't deleted. i'm confused.

As for the other answer, is extremely low quality, but provided clear instructions to the author on how to solve their problem.  Since it doesn’t ask a question, and answers the author’s question, it’s considered an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I've always been a little confused by the rules here. I'm my mind "it sounds like access enumeration is enabled" is introducing original poster to the term "access based enumeration" so he can go learn about access based enumeration, which will immediately tell him how to disable it. I don't understand the requirement to spoonfeed "access based enumeration is enabled. Therefore disabling access based enumeration will solve your problem, therefore you should disable access based enumeration. Therefore you should follow steps a b c."

Comment: Perhaps the steps to disable access based enumeration might differ based on the method by which his users access the folders, which is why I asked "how are your users accessing the folders" before offering instructions.

Comment: If the original post is not clear, are we  not allowed to to ask for clarification? We just have two give answers based on on all possible interpretations? Or are questions only allowed on comments, which are only allowed once we get sufficient reputation?

Comment: @curtmchirt - You should not be submitting an answer if a question isn’t clear.

Comment: The bottom line is your answer had a great deal to be desired, it didn’t contain any real information on how to solve the author’s problem, and it was clear the question wasn’t clear enough to actually be answered since your answer contained a question.  The fact a similar answer wasn’t deleted, an answer I maintain had its own problems, has nothing to do with your answer being deleted.

Comment: @curtmcgirt if the question is not clear and you need to ask for clarification then you should post a comment under the question. You cannot do that at the moment as it requires 50 rep to post comments, so for now you should submit clear answers that don't ask for clarification.